# How to overlap master page over detail page in masterdetailpage xamarin forms in iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using master detail page. In iOS when I click hamburger icon the master page slides the detail page to right in iOS. I want when we click on hamburger icon the master page should come over detail page like in android. The detail page should not slide to right, it should stable and Master page should overlap it in ios. In android its working fine. How can I achieve it in ios also?

Comment: did you got any solutions

Answer (score 0):

In your **Master Detail Page** Xaml or CS file you need to set the attribute **MasterBehaviour** to be equal to the type [Popover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.masterbehavior?view=xamarin-forms).

You must then on pressing the hamburger icon change the IsPresented variable from false to true or the reverse if you would like to slide the drawer out  or back in.

Xamarin.Forms currently (v3.40) have a pretty terrible implementation of the MasterDetailPage I have raised issues on GitHub and I am currently working on a pull request to fix their bugs for them.